# Would the following organisation be under the UN's Military Staff Committee in a realistic scenario?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, politics, alternate-history, military

So, looking at the situation, yes, this is a scenario where Earth comes under attack. I will start to copy-paste and update the lore as I write this question.....now:

The Gdarje (the name of the extraterrestrials) initially began to investigate Earth with probes and research vessels as early as WWI (in real life, this is untrue), but in 1961 (the first PoD), an extraterrestrial research vessel is shot down by US F-4 Phantom IIs and Guatemalan P-51s, (the latter being completely wiped out by infrared lasers), initially thinking it was a Soviet experimental spy plane (an assumption taken from its starting trajectory above Cuba), and then a joint operation between US Green Berets and anti-Castro militants who were training that night on 9 March, 1961, managed to secure the crash site and eliminate all four survivors (albeit with heavy casualties in the process), though most of physical evidence the incident occurred was destroyed, though after-action reports, a few computer systems, a man-portable coilgun and photographic evidence were preserved, which proved to be useful 14 years later in the UN Convention on Extraterrestrial Interference. This lead to the formation of the United Nations Extraterrestrial Investigation Committee in secret, with the intent of investigating the Incident, preservation of the evidence and study of the captured technology, which had side-effects as you will now see. Unknown to the Americans or the rest of the world, prior to being killed, one of the survivors sent an emergency transmission to their nearby military outpost in Alpha Centauri (which took four years to arrive, and months to spread across the Grand Hegemony of Fanghdar (the name of their government and Fanghdar being their origin world and a hypothetical moon of the real life HD 37124 c, which the human designation following the discovery is HD 37124 c m XVIII (the planet has 18 moons, Fanghdar being the 8th moon in terms of distance to the planet's core and Roche limit), and I say months because of the wormhole network connecting their fledgling (but already dangerous) interstellar civilisation, fledgling because the furthest presence they have is in Alpha Centauri, although they do have a newly founded colony in a habitable moon of Gliese 876 b), and two years they spend preparing to invade us (and bringing in spacecraft with construction materials to last for a minimum of either 27 years or 57 years, I cannot decide and this is counting the 7 year trip to Earth, because antimatter beam core engines), which leads to interesting side-effects due to butterflies as previously mentioned. Kennedy survives assaasination, although Vietnam still intensifies, but not to OTL levels, which results in Nixon winning against LBJ, ARPANET comes online two years earlier, along with CYCLADES two years later, and of course, by 1975, their research vessels begin intensifying their observations and also begin to establish a permanent presence in our Solar System (including Earth, although outposts on Earth are on low priority to them until they can establish infrastructure to secure natural resources elsewhere in the Solar System later to be used against us), and eventually, as their research efforts intensify and governments begin to become worried, combined with the first attempts to form pro-extraterrestrial insurgents, the UN Convention on Extraterrestrial Interference begins in an unspecified location (originally it was supposed to be the UN HQ, but then I realised it would get so much media attention, now it is a base in Djibouti, at the time a French colony, known as Base Aérienne 188), and the convention results in the formation of the United Nations Extraterrestrial Response Unit (UNERU), which is basically a more realistic version of XCOM, on 30 June, 1975, along with the invocation of Article 47 of the UN Charter, and the integration of the UNEIC into UNERU's R&D Division (more on it later), with 1 July, 1975 being when operations under the organisation start, which is when the novel known as Skies Above Earth (authored by me) starts.

Here are the organisation's subdivisions:

1. UNERU Research and Development Division (est. 1961 as the United Nations Extraterrestrial Investigation Committee (UNEIC for short)) - Conducts UNERU's R&D on reverse-engineering extraterrestrial technology.
2. UNERU Manufacturing Division (est. 1980)* - Manufacutures military equipment derived from extraterrestrial technology.
3. UNERU Public Relations Division (est. 1976) - Negotiates contracts and handles recruitment of new personnel and officers, without having to rely on the armed forces of UN Security Council member nations (permanent or otherwise).
4. UNERU Counter-Terrorism Bureau (est. 1975) - Roots out extraterrestrial infiltrators and conducts counter-terrorism and counter-insurgency operations pro-Extraterrestrial terrorist groups and sympathisers.
5. UNERU Aerospace Forces (est. 1975 as UNERU Air Forces) - Shoot down extraterrestrial craft (early and mid war); establish both orbital and atmospheric dominance and provide tactical support to UNERU forces (late war). They are normally filled with personnel from the nation they are stationed in, and are subordinate to a national command, which depends on the nation you are stationed in.
6. UNERU National Commands (est. 1975) - Controls UNERU's Rapid Response Units, mainly used to secure the majority of crashed and landed extraterrestrial craft, and assault small extraterrestrial bases worldwide, each team hosting personnel from the nation it is stationed in.
7. UNERU Regional Commands in North America, Central America, South America, Western Europe, Eastern Europe, Scandinavia, Middle East, Norh Africa, West Africa, South Africa, East Africa, Central Asia, South Asia, East Asia, and Oceania (est. 1975) - Controls regional task forces composed of various personnel from the 15 members of the UN Security Council (later extended to the rest of the UN), normally used to secure larger extraterrestrial craft, attack larger extraterrestrial bases worldwide (later extended to the rest of the Solar System), and respond to extraterrestrial raids on populated areas, with major cities given top priority, as well as centres of government.
8. UNERU Global Command (est. 1975) - Controls the entirety of UNERU operations worldwide (later extended to the rest of the Solar System) and answers only to the UN Security Council, via the Military Staff Committee (which is the intent of the question at hand), led by The Commander (whose details still need to be further fleshed out).

NOTE: The asterisk refers to proposed dates of establishment, meaning the time the UNERU Manufacturing Division is established is undecided.

Alright, so based on this: could UNERU realistically need to be subordinate to the Military Staff Committee or directly to the UN Security Council?

Comment: I don't think we need the background on the aliens since your question has nothing to do with them, and everything to do with politics. The reason I say this is because your post is a massive wall of text that will discourage people (myself included) from fully reading it. Stick to only providing the facts necessary to answer your query: **"An organization is doing research on alien tech on behalf of the UN. Would they fall under the authority of the Military Staff Committee or  the UN Security Council?"** Done.

Comment: Good point. I just copy-pasted this from two threads back in alternatehistory.com. So....... :/

Comment: And I am giving a background on the book as a whole, with the Gdarje being part of it. And the emphasis mainly goes to UNERU, which is not just doing research on their technology but also fighting extraterrestrials. The UNEIC/UNERU R&D Division is doing the research.

Comment: And meh. I can have a moderator help. :P

Comment: Please clean up the post as mentioned by @AndreiROM that is a lot of superfluous information.

Comment: Down voted because there is simply too much background stuff, plus you didn't make it any easier to read by not having paragraphs. I'd be happy to upvote again if you make it more concise and readable.

Comment: I think the most unrealistic part of this is that the U.N.did something and did it effectively. I mean, seriously, When has that happened in real life? Rwandan genocide, anyone?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Well, it was either that or the world ends so........

Comment: So their organization just changed its fundamental nature? Likely story. In any case, I'd follow the advice of the answers and have Russia and her allies and the US and its allies.

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s highly unlikely that this organization would form as part of the UN *at all*.

In the middle of the arms race that was the Cold War, you’ve got alien spacecraft and advanced weapons starting to pop up. The existence and threat of extraterrestrials is not going to magically unite the planet during one of its most divided and paranoid historical periods. Both Russia and the United States will be scrambling internally to research and manufacture these weapons and it’s very unlikely that they would be collaborating on any of it. The United States might well push for enhanced militaristic capacities in the UN, but Russia would almost certainly view that as a NATO takeover of the organization and withdraw, possibly taking other nations with it.

The United States and her allies may be more willing to collaborate on research and security efforts against an alien threat, but the chief nations capable of providing resources are almost all NATO members. This makes it fairly likely that your organization would first be born from NATO and possibly detach into its own entity. Russia, on the other hand, would have her own internal organization. Now, during the battle between the west and communism, there’s a new tool that both sides can brandish: protection from alien threats. Both Russia and the NATO nations would be eager to dangle their resources, experience, and technology as a political carrot to strategic developing nations worldwide.

Frankly, I wouldn’t put it past either faction to *ally with the alien species* long before humanity decided to unite together during that period of history.

Comment: UN is assumed in question and I do not think it is a coincidence timeline starts when Nikita Khrushchev was in power in the USSR. He was actually fairly pragmatic, so "cooperate against external threat" would have appealed to him. Would have brought back memories of WWII and alliance against the Nazis too...

Comment: Come to think of it, most political and military leaders in major nations would have been personally involved in the World War 2. So a sudden thaw in face of external threat is maybe more practical than actual events suggest?

Comment: @VilleNiemi I concur. Khrushchev would need to take this into consideration, and (unlesss the Butterfly Effect has somehow kept Khruschev in power), the same problem will need to be considered by Brezhnev.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, it is far more likely that the various already existing alliances and military forces will swing into action on their own. Firstly they have already existing mandates and resources. Secondly, they are specifically tasked to defend their territories, while the UN has no specific incentives *to do anything at all* (consider that General Lewis Mackenzie was unable to contact UNHQ during the siege of Sarajevo *during a shooting war* because the UNHQ kept 9-5 office hours [based on local time in NYC]. You can read this in his book [Peacekeeper](https://www.amazon.ca/Peacekeeper-Road-Sarajevo-Lewis-MacKenzie/dp/155054098X?tag=duckduckgo-d-20). The UN response to genocide in Rwanda and South Sudan also does not provide a great deal of confidence in their aptitude and abilities).

If anything, there may be a mad scramble in the UN as various second and third tier nations try and get in on the act, and UN Bureaucrats decide to impose themselves on the various military forces which are working on the issue. One can only imagine the response at NORAD HQ when the commanding General is told the UN is on the phone....

Eventually several supranational alliance structures may "settle in" to the role and form formal or informal lines of communication and cooperation between each other to minimize frictions and coordinate resources. The United States will probably be the ringleader of the circus, given its preeminance in so many existing multinational military alliances and organizations (NATO, NORAD, SEATO, OAS, etc.). At this time, the Europeans might form something based on the European Economic Community, The United Kingdom might upgrade the Commonwealth into an active organization and the Soviet Union would be controlling the resources of the Warsaw Pact. China would be a very second rate player in this time period, as would the other BRIC nations not already named.

A fun story idea might be to look into the workings of the UN body as a massive bureaucracy which is fighting to expand and control access to resources *despite having no functional role at all* outside of the UN. Bureaucrats trying to baffle various UN functionaries into believing they do have a role to play in planetary defense would be a true "[Catch 22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eXI4uy3Mlg)" situation

Answer (score 1):

Anything you want, really.

MSC never did much of practical use in the real world, so real history is utterly useless in determining what its relationship to UNERU would be.

UNERU could be entirely separate. Since MSC never did much, people might simply sidestep it for defending the planet.

UNERU could be subservient to MSC. Since MSC never did much, there would be no real interference either way with its "other duties".

UNERU could be MSC renamed and repurposed. Since MSC never did much, there would be no real interference either way with its "other duties".

You catch my drift?

Comment: So, no need for UNERU to be controlled by the Military Staff Committee even if reactivated?

Comment: @FutureHistorian I do not think the UN charter has any particular requirements on how to organise fighting aliens. The solution would be whatever politicians decide when making the new convention. If the permanent members would want to dominate UNERU but do not feel like arguing that directly, they could argue for using MSC. As superior organization if they just want oversight, as the direct basis if they want direct control. Although the permanent members are hardly a unified political block. So it all still comes down to: whatever you want.

Comment: I understand, but I need to know if this scenario is anywhere near realistic regarding the MSC.

Comment: @FutureHistorian Your basic scenario involves alien invasion. Neither real history nor any UN rules is particularly relevant as to the specifics of the response such as your question. Realism would come from handling the **politics** of the situation right. And even there it would involve creating **entirely new** politics based on historical situation and personalities.

Comment: Good point.........I should take that into consideration. I am just trying to retain both scientific and historical/alternate historical accuracy.